# How can I use splatting in a parameterized function?

Tags: powershell, parameters, parameter-passing, powershell-3.0

I'm  writing a parameterized function and trying to use splatting to reuse the parameter-set.

```
$Computername='localhost'

$params = @{'computername'=$Computername;
           'credential'='administrator'}

function Get-Diskinfo {
    Param ($drive,$computername,$credential)

    Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DeviceID = '$drive'" @params
}
```

On executing like this it fails doesn't recognize the user-inputed servername. It still takes the value of `$Computername` initially specified.

`Get-Diskinfo -drive c: Server1 administrator`

How can I get it to identify the user-inputed computername? Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of splatting random hashtable, you need to splat something that is defined automatically by PowerShell:

```
function Get-Diskinfo {
Param ($drive,$computername,$credential)

# Need to remove any parameter that is used "internally" and don't exist on cmdlet
$PSBoundParameters.Remove('drive') | Out-Null

    Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DeviceID = '$drive'" @PSBoundParameters

}

Get-Diskinfo -drive c: Server1 administrator
```

Alternatively: use passed parameters to build $parms inside your function:

```
function Get-Diskinfo {
Param ($drive,$computername,$credential)

$parms = @{
    computername = $Computername
    credential = $credential
}

Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DeviceID = '$drive'" @parms
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't calling `@parms` until inside your function.

This should work, using the parameters within your function to pull the WMI query:

```
$Computername='localhost'
$parms = @{'computername'=$Computername;
    'credential'='administrator'}

function Get-Diskinfo {
    Param ($drive,$computername,$credential)
    Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DeviceID = '$drive'" -ComputerName $computername -Credential $credential
    }
```

And then use the splatting to run the function:

```
Get-Diskinfo -drive c: @parm
```

The function can still be run using the parameters directly:

```
Get-Diskinfo -drive c: Server1 administrator
```

Comment: But that beats the purpose. The user of the script needs to be able to enter the servername of his choice.

Comment: You can still pass the computer name to the function using either the hash table with splatting or the -ComputerName parameter. The problem with your script is that $parm is set outside the function, called inside the function, but never passed to the function.

Comment: The end user shouldn't have to use the @parms array. I am trying to write multiple similar functions and reuse this common parameter-set. So it has to be set outside the function and called inside the function.

Comment: I answered the question that was asked. You have $Computername contained within $parms. If you want something different you should edit the question.

Comment: Params shouldn't even be an array.  Why not just use PowerShells built-in param feature?

Answer (score 2):

Your `$params` hashtable gets it's value when you create it, not when it's used. Your `$computername,$credential` parameters are never referenced inside your function, which means that they are dead parameters.

You can't use splatting and normal function-calling with parameters for the same parameter at the same time. You should only use parameters inside your function scriptblock. Splatting is for the end-user only. @Tim Ferril has shown you how to write the function properly.

If you need to be able to use both default values AND be able to change ex. `ComputerName` for one cmdlet, then you should use default values and not splatting. Ex:

```
function Test-Global {
param(
    $ComputerName = $global:PC,
    $Username = $global:username
)

"Computername is '$ComputerName'"
"Username is '$UserName'"
}

#Set the reusable variables in global scope and call your function
$global:Username = "Frode"
$global:PC = "MyPC"

PS C:\Users\Frode> Test-Global
Computername is 'MyPC'
Username is 'Frode'

#If I need to modify the server for one function, I'd simply specify that parameter
PS C:\Users\Frode> Test-Global -ComputerName server1
Computername is 'server1'
Username is 'Frode'
```

To make it easier for user to set the default values, you could create a function for that too.

```
#Create your reusable parameters
function Set-Params {
param(
    $ComputerName,
    $Username
)
    if($Username) { $global:Username = $Username }
    if($ComputerName) { $global:PC = $ComputerName }
}

PS C:\Users\Frode> Set-Params -ComputerName Test1 -Username Test1

PS C:\Users\Frode> Test-Global
Computername is 'Test1'
Username is 'Test1'

PS C:\Users\Frode> Set-Params -ComputerName Test2

PS C:\Users\Frode> Test-Global
Computername is 'Test2'
Username is 'Test1'
```

Comment: "You can't use splatting and normal function-calling with parameters for the same parameter at the same time."  ...This is what I needed to know.

Comment: I am writing multiple functions that use the `$Computername` and the `$Credentials` parameters in them. I thought I could use splatting to declare them once as a global parameter-set and then reuse them in all the functions. Deduplicate my code if I may....

Comment: You still can.. see my answer.. By using a function or module script to declare som global variables and specifying them as default values in your function's parameters, you can have your global parameter-set AND the ability to modify the values when you need it.

Comment: But the user will have to run 2 commands instead of one ? Can I call `Set-Params` inside each function ?

Comment: Yes. You only use `Set-Params` to change the default values. If you need to specify a different computer for one function-call, you'd just specify it like `test-globals -computername anothercompuer`.